# Curl's @file equivalent in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, curl

I have a curl command that looks like this:

```
curl -u secret: -X POST https://api.flood.io/floods \
-F "flood[tool]=jmeter" \
-F "flood[threads]=10" \
-F "flood[rampup]=60" \
-F "flood[duration]=300" \
-F "flood[privacy]=public" \
-F "flood[name]=Performance Test" \
-F "flood_files[]=@SitemapPerfTest.jmx" \
-F "flood[grids][][infrastructure]=demand" \
-F "flood[grids][][instance_quantity]=1" \
-F "flood[grids][][region]=us-west-2" \
-F "flood[grids][][instance_type]=m5.xlarge" \
-F "flood[grids][][stop_after]=5"
```

I am trying to write the equivalent command in powershell, but am struggling with the `@SitemapPerfText.jmx` portion.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
$username = "secret"
$password = ""
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))

$floodFile = [IO.File]::ReadAllText('SitemapPerfTest.jmx');

$params = @{
 "flood[tool]"="jmeter";
 "flood[threads]"="10";
 "flood[rampup]"="60";
 "flood[duration]"="300";
 "flood[privacy]"="public";
 "flood[name]"="Performance Test";
 "flood_files[]"="$floodFile";
 "flood[grids][][infrastructure]"="demand";
 "flood[grids][][instance_quantity]"="1";
 "flood[grids][][region]"="us-west-2";
 "flood[grids][][instance_type]"="m5.xlarge";
 "flood[grids][][stop_after]"="5";
}

Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method Post -Uri "https://api.flood.io/floods" `
  -ContentType 'multipart/form-data' `
  -Body $params
```

However, it seems that the remote service does not recognize the file I am sending up.  What is the equivalent powershell command to the `@file` parameter in cURL?

Comment: does `$floodFile` appear to have the content you are looking for? Is it a text file?

Comment: Yes, it's an xml file.

Comment: What you are doing looks correct. Do you get an error, or is the file just missing when you check afterwards?